# Sharing C: on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions, network-shares

How do I share C: drive on a Windows 7 Pro computer, for access from a Windows 10 machine?

I can share individual folders on C: but not the root. If I do share it and set permissions so that everyone has full control, I can see the share on my Win10 machine but when I try and access it I get an error message:

Windows cannot access \CompName\c
You do not have permission to access \CompName\c. Contact your network administrator to request access.

I do have the permissions set (I've checked and double checked). network discovery is on, file and printer sharing is on, password protected sharing is off.

Sharing a folder on c: works fine just not the root.

Comment: IIRC the problem is with UAC. Even if you log in with an admin account you’re not an admin. // Other than that, NTFS ACLs also apply to shares. Maybe check them too.

Comment: I can see the share on my Win10 machine but when I try and access it I get an error message:  ... Turn ON Password protected sharing and make sure the drive share has a name and password that you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Problem found, although the share was set for Everyone to have full control the disk root wasn't.

Comment: Sure hope you didn't do this. You may have destroyed whatever security was left in Windows 7.